# How to use the result of a macro and not the macro itself?

Tags: urls, accents

I would like to use the result of a macro (that delete accentuated characters of a string variable called `\name`), saved in a variable called `\nameSA`, in a url. I thought that I could use the `\nameSA` directly in the url argument as I can do with my original variable `\name`, but the url sees the macro and not the result of the macro. Could you tell me please how I can save and reuse the result of the macro instead of the macro itself ? I searched and tried different options but it was unsuccessful...

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode,breaklinks=true,hyperindex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

%This is the macro to delete accents in a string
\makeatletter
\def\delaccent[#1]#2{% #1=liste des substitutions
\begingroup
\expandarg\exploregroups\edef\temp{#2}%
\delaccent@i#1\delaccent@i\delaccent@i
\expandafter\temp\endgroup}
\def\delaccent@i#1#2{\ifx\delaccent@i#1\else\StrSubstitute\temp{\noexpand#1}{\noexpand#2}[\temp]\expandafter\delaccent@i\fi}
\makeatother

% I define a string with accentuated characters and I use the previous macro to delete accents.
\newcommand{\name}{énergie}
\newcommand\nameSA{\delaccent[{à}{a}{é}{e}{è}{e}{ë}{e}{ê}{e}{ï}{i}{ô}{o}{ù}{u}]{\name}}

\begin{document}
Name with accents : \name

Name without accent : \nameSA % --> Works fine

URL with accents : \url{https://www.\name.com} --> Works fine

URL without accent : \url{https://www.\nameSA.com} %--> Did not work (compilation failed)
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose a different strategy, because `\url` is not able to execute all the substitutions before printing the name and also for better efficiency.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\delaccent}[3][]{% #1=liste des substitutions
  \begingroup
  \expandarg\exploregroups\edef\temp{#3}%
  \delaccent@i#2\delaccent@i\delaccent@i
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \temp
    \expandafter\endgroup
  \else
    \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\newcommand\noexpand#1{\temp}}%
    \expandafter\x
  \fi
}
\def\delaccent@i#1#2{%
  \ifx\delaccent@i#1%
  \else
    \StrSubstitute\temp{\noexpand#1}{\noexpand#2}[\temp]%
  \expandafter\delaccent@i
 \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\declarestring}[3]{%
  \newcommand{#1}{#3}%
  \delaccent[#2]{{à}{a}{é}{e}{è}{e}{ë}{e}{ê}{e}{ï}{i}{ô}{o}{ù}{u}}{#3}%
}


\declarestring{\name}{\nameSA}{Michaël}

\begin{document}

Name : \name

Try 1 : \delaccent{{à}{a}{é}{e}{è}{e}{ë}{e}{ê}{e}{ï}{i}{ô}{o}{ù}{u}}{Michaël}

Try 2 : \delaccent{{à}{a}{é}{e}{è}{e}{ë}{e}{ê}{e}{ï}{i}{ô}{o}{ù}{u}}{\name}

Try 3 : \nameSA


Name with accents : \name

Name without accent : \nameSA % --> Works fine

URL with accents : \url{https://www.\name.com}

URL without accent : \url{https://www.\nameSA.com}

\end{document}
```

So `\definestring` defines both the “normal” string and the “sans accent” one.

Note that the redesigned version of `\delaccent` has an optional argument that can contain a macro name, which will be defined to the “deaccented” string; if there's no optional argument, the “deaccented” string is printed.

[image]

---

A different implementation, with perhaps a better syntax for the replacements:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\delaccent}{omm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \nezluge_delaccent:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { \tl_use:N }
   }
   {
    \nezluge_delaccent:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { \tl_set:NV #1 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\declarestring}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx #1 { #3 }
  \delaccent [ #2 ] { à/a, é/e, è/e, ë/e, ê/e, ï/i, ô/o, ù/u } {#3}
}

\tl_new:N \l__nezluge_delaccent_string_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nezluge_delaccent:nnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__nezluge_delaccent_string_tl { #2 }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \__nezluge_delaccent_replace:n { ##1 }
   }
  #3 \l__nezluge_delaccent_string_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nezluge_delaccent_replace:n
 {
  \__nezluge_delaccent_replace_aux:w #1 \q_stop
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__nezluge_delaccent_replace_aux:w #1 / #2 \q_stop
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \l__nezluge_delaccent_string_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\declarestring{\name}{\nameSA}{Michaël}

\begin{document}

Name : \name

Try 1 : \delaccent{à/a, é/e, è/e, ë/e, ê/e, ï/i, ô/o, ù/u}{Michaël}

Try 2 : \delaccent{à/a, é/e, è/e, ë/e, ê/e, ï/i, ô/o, ù/u}{\name}

Try 3 : \nameSA


Name with accents : \name

Name without accent : \nameSA % --> Works fine

URL with accents : \url{https://www.\name.com}

URL without accent : \url{https://www.\nameSA.com}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: If “exploring groups” is not necessary, the replacement macro can be made much more efficient.