# How get the result of a macro that uses xstring functions before writing to a file

Tags: expansion, xstring, write

I encountered the need to write last name with initials (extracted from the full author's string based on first chars of first and middle name) into an external file. I use the `xstring` package to separate the string and "cut out" the initials. However, the text of the macro is written to the file, not the result of "calculating" the initials.

Here is a highly simplified example that just "calculates" the initials for any string consisting of two words separated by space or `~`. I need a solution that will work with UTF-8 since the class will use Cyrillic, but here just for simplicity I also omitted the settings for Cyrillic.

I somehow need to get the same in the file as on the screen, but I'm completely confused about the expansion of the commands and any help and hints is appreciated. I apologize if the answer is somewhere here. I found [How to use the result of a macro and not the macro itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292383/how-to-use-the-result-of-a-macro-and-not-the-macro-itself) only, but this is a slightly different topic (or just I didn't figure out how to apply it in my case).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring,newfile}

\newoutputstream{file}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.txt}{file}

\begin{document}

\def\author{John Doe}

\def\initials#1{%
    \expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{~}{ }[\temp]%
    \StrChar{\temp}{1}[\FirstInitial]%
    \StrBehind{\temp}{ }[\second]%
    \StrChar{\second}{1}[\SecondInitial]%
    \FirstInitial. \SecondInitial.%
}

\author
\addtostream{file}{\author}

\initials{\author}    
\addtostream{file}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\initials{\author}}}

\closeoutputstream{file}

\end{document}
```

I see on the screen:

[image]

and i get in external file now

```
John Doe
\expandarg \StrSubstitute {\author }{~}{ }[\temp ]\StrChar {\temp }{1}[\FirstInitial ]\StrBehind {\temp }{ }[\second ]\StrChar {\second }{1}[\SecondInitial ]\FirstInitial . \SecondInitial .
```

P.S. In fact, there may be several calls to the `\author` macro, which is implemented by the following code inside a macro `\saveauthorrus` which takes two parameters Last Name and other, which takes First Name and Middle Name on the basis of which initials are "calculated"

```
\newcommand{\saveauthorrus}[2][]{

 ....

\xdef\authorslist@ru@lfm{%
    \ifx\authorslist@ru@lfm\@empty%
        \unexpanded{#1~\initials{#2}}%
    \else
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\authorslist@ru@lfm},
        \unexpanded{#1~\initials{#2}}%
    \fi
}%
```

}

Unfortunately, calling the function `\initials` leads to the fact that the correct Last Name accumulates in `\authorslist@ru@lfm`, but the identic (last calculated) initials of the First Name and Middle Name.

**P.S.**

I will simplify (and complicate the problem at the same time). I need to do the assignment written above in a loop. As a result, for the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\gdef\tmp{}
\newcommand{\rd}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{-}{}[\str]\gdef\tmp{\str}}

\begin{document}
\newwrite\txt
\immediate\openout\txt=\jobname.txt

\newcount\somecounter
\somecounter = 3
\newcount\i
\i = 0
\loop
    \advance\i 1
    \the\i-a-b-c -
    \rd{\the\i-a-b-c}%
    \tmp\par
    \immediate\write\txt{\expandafter\unexpanded{\tmp}}
\ifnum \i < \somecounter
\repeat

\closeout\txt
\end{document}
```

Here `\somecounter` is a counter that is already defined globally for this article, but for simplicity it is hard set in the example. And I get on the screen

[image]

but in the file always

```
\tmp 
\tmp 
\tmp
```

How do I define a variable that will temporarily take the current value from the loop and write it to a file? I am interested in some general solution since I have a lot of such situations

Comment: `xstring` commands don't work in a `\write` (`\addtostream`) like that.  You have to first call `\initials` _outside_ of `\addtostream`, then do `\addtostream{file}{\FirstInitial. \SecondInitial}`.  Or use something else

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Phelype! I get the idea, thanks, but if it needs to be done many times (in a loop or by concatenating author's strings, for example, if the `\author` command is written to be called many times), then the `\FirstInitial` and `\SecondInitial` variables will only contain the results of the last assignment and the initials of all authors will be the same

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik excuse me again, could you tell me what to do in the second case? (after P.S.)

Comment: The correct is `\expandafter\unexpanded{\tmp}` doesn't expand `\tmp`.  You want `\unexpanded\expandafter{\tmp}`.  After you do that you'll get `\str` in the file, rather than `\tmp`, because you need to expand that twice.  To do that, either change `\gdef` (in `\rd`) by `\xdef`, or use `\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\tmp}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks! You have helped me a lot!